# Leaflet polygon draw a weird shape

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I am using **Leaflet map** in my page and I have to show a **polygon**. I get the **vertices** of the shape from my Node controller and then add them to the map using the following way:

```js
    function fetchAreas(){
        const url='http://localhost:1337/api/areas';
        fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);

            for(d in data){
                var polvertices = [];
                for(c in data[d].Coords)
                    polvertices.push([data[d].Coords[c].Latitude, data[d].Coords[c].Longitude]);

                L.polygon(polvertices, {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                }).addTo(map);
            }
        });
    }
```

As a **result** I get the following *weird shape*:
[image]

I discovered it is caused by **vertices' longitude order**, so ordering them by lon. in the controller query result in *an other weird shape*:
[image]

So now I am wondering how can I show it correctly or if I am missing something in my code because [leaflet example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) does not show too much.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what should it look like?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Nvm I figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the solution to this problem is the **order of vertices in the coords array**, passed to the polygon: they must follow the order of the perimeter of the shape.

I mean if you have to draw a `rectangle` like this

```
A +--------------+ B
  |              |
  |              |
D +--------------+ C
```

using the function

```
L.polygon(verticesArray).addTo(map);
```

you must add the `vertices` (`[lat, lon]`) in the **correct order**, coming back to the rectangle, the correct order must be `[A, B, C, D]`.

Not respecting the order may cause **errors** like in my *original question*.